# convert various source data_types schema to synapse data types schema mapping framework

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, azure-synapse

In order to convert various source data_types to  Azure synapse data types to generate ddl so that data can be injected through a PySpark framework. For that I have to use the datatypes dictionary which contains distinct source data types mapped to synapse data types shown below as 'distinct_data_types_source2synapse'. But the actual columns list that I am getting from meta data is like a list of tuples shown below as 'column_list'. Need to find a way to convert source specific data type to synapse data type in columnist so that I can generate DDL to inject data in Azure synapse.

```
distinct_data_types_source2synapse = {
    'DATE': 'DATE',
    'PERIOD TIME': 'DATETIME',
    'NUMERIC': 'INT',
    'UROWID': 'VARCHAR',
    'DATETIME2': 'DATETIME2',
    'INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE': '',
    'PERIOD TIMESTAMP': '',
    'BINARY': 'VARBINARY',
    'DECFLOAT': 'FLOAT',
    'DATETIME': 'DATETIME',
    'VARCHAR': 'VARCHAR' }

column_list = ['[profile_id] VARCHAR NOT NULL', '[age] NUMERIC NOT NULL', '[tenure] PERIOD TIME NULL']
```

expected output columnlist as

```
['[profile_id] VARCHAR NOT NULL', '[age] INT NOT NULL', '[tenure] DATETIME NULL']
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
s=pd.Series(column_list)
for i in s:
  print(i.split())
  v= i.split()
  if v[1] in distinct_data_types_source2synapse keys():
    print("yes..change column type")
  else:
    print("no don't change")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_type_mapping = { 'DATE': 'DATE', 'PERIODTIME': 'DATETIME', 'NUMERIC': 'INT', 'UROWID': 'VARCHAR', 'DATETIME2': 'DATETIME2', 'INTERVAL DAY TO MINUTE': '', 'PERIOD TIMESTAMP': '', 'BINARY': 'VARBINARY', 'DECFLOAT': 'FLOAT', 'DATETIME': 'DATETIME', 'VARCHAR': 'VARCHAR' }

l = ['[profile_id] VARCHAR NOT NULL', '[age] NUMERIC NOT NULL', '[tenure] PERIODTIME NULL']

str = ""

for i in l:
    str += (i)
    str += (", ")
   

#print(str)

l1 = str.split(" ")
l2 = ([data_type_mapping.get(n, n) for n in l1])
print(' '.join(l2)[:-2])
```

#this would work perfectly, if there are no spaces in keys of the dictionary.